# Python RuntimeError GPIO

Tags: python, gpio

there.
I'm tring to let a Script run by using a switch, to switch the workloop on and off.

the 'switch pin' is pin 13. With this input, what has already a setup with 'GPIO.setup(13, GPIO,IN)', i can turn the loop on.
But when i'm tring to get the input inside the loop i'll get a runtimerror (Code and Traceback below).

```
    while True:
    d = datalogger(devmode)
    d.set_sheet()


    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
    print 'Ready !'
    break

while 1:
    if GPIO.input(13) == False:
    d.runner(True)
    break
    else:
        pass


while d.running:

    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=d.hall_sens)

    d.time_lauf()
    d.abrieb_a()
    d.read_temp()
    d.clear_temp_log()
    d.write_sheet()
    d.print_data()
    d.loop_break(looptime)

    s = GPIO.input(13)

    if s == 1:
    d.runner(False)
    else:
    pass

    GPIO.remove_event_detect(23)

Traceback (most recent call last):
file "file.py", line 260, in <module>
s = GPIO.input(13)
RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first
```

but i did

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use BCM numbering instead of board numbering and then declare your pins again.